# Missed Block with "Error Found No Ledger corresponding to ledger:..."

Tags: baking, ledger, solo-baking

Missed a block and saw the following error on the baker terminal window (Ubuntu)

"Error Found no ledger corresponding to ledger://xxx..."

This made me think that there might be a connectivity issue but list all ledgers command perfectly shows the ledger with the right credentials.

Node was also up and running.

I am on 7.x not 8.x.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your ledger might have disconnected.

Run the following tezos-client command to see connected ledgers.

```
tezos-client list connected ledgers
```

It should output something like the following when connected:

```
## Ledger `adjective0-animal0-adjective1-animal1`
Found a Tezos Baking 2.2.5 (git-description: "") application running on
Ledger Nano S at [0004:0002:00].

To use keys at BIP32 path m/44'/1729'/0'/0' (default Tezos key path), use one
of:
  tezos-client import secret key ledger "ledger://adjective0-animal0-adjective1-animal1/bip25519/0h/0h"
  tezos-client import secret key ledger "ledger://adjective0-animal0-adjective1-animal1/ed25519/0h/0h"
  tezos-client import secret key ledger "ledger://adjective0-animal0-adjective1-animal1/secp256k1/0h/0h"
  tezos-client import secret key ledger "ledger://adjective0-animal0-adjective1-animal1/P-256/0h/0h"
```